# Simbolic links when migrating laravel to server

Tags: laravel

I'm developing with laravel in windows with xampp. I'm using crudbooster to generate cruds and admin panel. In some directories there are simbolic links to vendor folder, but this simbolic links are lost when I upload files to my server. What must i do in order to preserve the links?
Best regards

Comment: What are you using these symbolic links for? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have not created that links. I think laravel and crudbooster had created them automatically.
I have two links pointing from 
<pre>
    /public/vendor/crudbooster ----> ../../vendor/crocodiscstudio/crudbooster/src/assets
    /public/storage --> ../storage/app/public
    /public/uploads ---> ../storage/app
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the symbolic links one time at the server. Then you have to exclude the symbolic links to be override. In our case, we use git. So we included the symbolic links into `.gitignore`.

We used to have the same issue every time we used to push our code into our production server. After we excluded the symbolic links, we did not have the same issue again.